# Using video.js library with Webpack's ProvidePlugin

Tags: javascript, webpack, video.js, webpack-2

I'm trying to upgrade Webpack from version 1 to version 3 in an application that uses the [video.js](https://github.com/videojs/video.js) library, and I want to expose `videojs` as a global variable to my scripts.

In my `webpack.config.js` file, in my `plugins` section, I have this:

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    videojs: 'video.js'
  })
]
```

Now, as an example, if I want to use the `registerPlugin` function, I have to do something like this (because `videojs.registerPlugin` is `undefined`):

```
videojs.default.registerPlugin(...);
```

I don't understand why I need to include `default` here!

I tried to use the array syntax:

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    videojs: ['video.js', 'videojs']
  })
]
```

But now my `videojs` global variable is `undefined`.

In the current application, I have the first syntax for the `ProvidePlugin`, and `videojs` variable is available globally, but I don't understand what's different in Webpack version 3. What am I missing here?

Any help is appreciated,
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found out how to solve the problem. The clue that I got is from the fact that I need to access the `registerPlugin` through the `default` property. So, in `webpack.config.js`, I can provide exactly that:

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    videojs: ['video.js', 'default']
  })
]
```

now, I can access `videojs.registerPlugin` function directly :)